# CORS Error when using const to add a stripe_account_id for connected accounts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, stripe-payments

I have set up Stripe Payment Request Buttons, everything is working when I manually add the stripeAccount: 'acct_XXX...', the payment succeeds on the dashboard for that connected account.

but when I try to put this in a const in payment_request_buttons.js:

```
const stripe_account_id = document.getElementById('stripe_account_id').value;

const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXX...'), {
  apiVersion: "2022-11-15",
  stripeAccount: stripe_account_id,
});
```

The hidden input:

```
<input id="stripe_account_id" type="hidden" value="<%= "'#{@user.stripe_account_id}'" %>">
```

I get this CORS error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present
```

I don't understand what the difference is manually inputting the account compared to using const?

I have just come across this error from a stripe link in the console:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "You did not provide an API key. You need to 
provide your API key in the Authorization header, using 
Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). 
See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, 
or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.",
"type": "invalid_request_error"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error.
 
When passing the stripe account manually you use an apostrophe " ' " with the account number inside, but when looking at the post data to stripe you see they are removed:

```
_stripe_account: acct_xxx...........
```

So in my ruby code i was adding the apostrophe in the value resulting in :

```
value="<%= "'#{@user.stripe_account_id}'" %>">

_stripe_account: 'acct_xxx...........'
```

being sent causing the error.
 
My updated ruby code without the apostrophe:

```
value="<%= @user.stripe_account_id %>">
```

This data was found in Network > wallet-config > Payload > Form Data

This has now resolved the CORS error and is working.